# I forgot how I cropped a video two years ago

Tags: windows-7, video, windows-live-movie-maker

Two years ago, I cropped a video on Windows 7 using Windows Live Movie Maker.  I cannot remember how I did it, but I know I did because I have the video from two years ago in three different sizes. One is the original that looks small and far away. Then I have  a second copy that looks bigger and closer and a third copy that is the biggest and closest.  I need to do this with another video and cannot figure out how I did it. It's driving me nuts! Can someone please tell me how to do it again?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

When you finish editing your video, and want to save it, you will have options, to choose which quality and size you want, or when you want to publish it to youtube you will have other options like custom quality and size

Comment: is quality & size not different that cropping ?

Comment: "looks bigger and closer" there is no option in movie maker that's gives you a feature to crop the video "I mean crop it like photo" but when you change the size of your video it's looks like you crop it / zoom-in, or you can do that by choosing different animation scene, it's look like zoom-in